# mplot3d tutorial examples are not running as they should

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I'm running into an issue when trying to run [standard matplotlib examples from the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#tri-surface-plots). For the plotting of a trisurface using `plot_trisurf` for the pringle example, two errors occur:

1. a single error:

   ```
   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override/matplotlib/collections.py:764: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt   scale = np.sqrt(self._sizes) * dpi / 72.0 * self._factor
   ```

and

2. an error for each point:

   ```
   Jul 28 11:12:13  python[77168] <Error>: void CGPathCloseSubpath(CGMutablePathRef _Nullable): no current point.
   ```

I'm using matplotlib 1.5.1
Here's the source/example code that I'm using:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n_angles = 36
n_radii = 8

# An array of radii
# Does not include radius r=0, this is to eliminate duplicate points
radii = np.linspace(0.125, 1.0, n_radii)

# An array of angles
angles = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n_angles, endpoint=False)

# Repeat all angles for each radius
angles = np.repeat(angles[..., np.newaxis], n_radii, axis=1)

# Convert polar (radii, angles) coords to cartesian (x, y) coords
# (0, 0) is added here. There are no duplicate points in the (x, y) plane
x = np.append(0, (radii*np.cos(angles)).flatten())
y = np.append(0, (radii*np.sin(angles)).flatten())

# Pringle surface
z = np.sin(-x*y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0.2)

plt.show()
```

and here is the plot:

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me. matplotlib 1.5.1, python 2.7.11, numpy 1.10.4, win 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

matplotlib version 2.2.2
python version 3
pyqt 5.9.2

Instead of

```
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
```

Try

```
ax = Axes3D(fig, rect=[0, 0, .95, 1], elev=45, azim=134)
```

Both works for me on Jupyter notebook.
I suspect you messed up the pyqt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbAwL.png)